# Performance degradation when using CrmServiceClient and AuthType OAuth in Dataverse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dataverse

I've got an ASP.NET MVC solution that calls the Dataverse API and I'm seeing a significant performance degradation when using `CrmServiceClient` and `AuthType=OAuth` compared with the ([soon to be deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-office365-deprecation)) WS-Trust connection (`AuthType=Office365`)

This is the code used for creating the `CrmServiceClient` connection (`AuthType=OAuth`)

```
var conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

var service = (IOrganizationService) conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

and this is the code used for creating WS-Trust connection (`AuthType=Office365`)

```
var target = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
            
target.ServiceConfigurationInstanceMode = ServiceConfigurationInstanceMode.PerName; 

var service = (OrganizationService) CrmConfigurationManager.CreateService(target, "DataverseServiceName");
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Does your code cache the security token? The connection string is crucial here. Please share.

Comment: I put an answer with more info, our issue was fixed by using the latest CrmSdk but also had to cache the IOrganizationService  per callerid. We cache it for an hour and then re create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case the issue was that we were using an old version of the CrmSdk, using the latest version (9.0.2.42) solved our problem
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/9.0.2.42

We also have issues with impersonation when setting the caller id (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.callerid?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-tooling-connector-crmserviceclient-callerid), if you are running several threads and initiating multiple connections with different callerids, we found that it's not thread safe and some calls to impersonate one user might get mixed up by another user even if:

- disablecrossthreadsafeties is set to false (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.disablecrossthreadsafeties?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-tooling-connector-crmserviceclient-disablecrossthreadsafeties)
- RequireNewInstance is set to true (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#connection-string-parameters)

We ended up having to cache each IOrganizationService per callerid to prevent it